# Login in Always On Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I am new to Always On Availability Groups and I am little bit confused with creation of logins.

Let's assume an environment NODE1(Primary) & NODE2(secondary) & NODE3(Stand by) & VAEWI(Listener).

1. I need to create a SQL authentication login.

   For this, I assume I need to create it by connecting to listener that which will sync in all of the nodes.
2. I need to create a Windows authentication.

   For this I think, as all of the nodes are window-clustered before creating the availability group. So, we need to create a Windows user 1st in primary node and then create a Windows authentication by connecting to the listener.

Can anyone let me know if my assumptions are true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting in a simple language :

```
A login gives you access to server.

A user gives you access to database.

A login must map a user so that you can access the database.
```

For SQL Authentication, you should create the login with SAME SID and map it to your user database/s on all the nodes with proper permissions (follow the principle of least privileged). [This script](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror) will help you or this [SSMS addin from sqlskills](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/synchronize-availability-group-logins-and-jobs/).

For Windows Authentication, you should create a login and map it to your user database. Create/transfer the same login to other nodes.

A listener is a virtual interface and has nothing to do with logins or users.

Comment: Can I just create a login and then mapped it to a user /database and do the same thing on the secondary ?

Comment: On Secondary, just create login with same sid. The db permissions are inherited.

Comment: I guess we need this for sql logins only not windows authenticated logins

Comment: Yes.. for windows login, you dont have to use sid, since sid for windows login never change. For sql logins, you have to use same sid across all nodes.